# Would a Chromebook running Linux handle android studio?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, chromebook

I'm going to get a Chromebook probably with a Celeron processor and probably 4GB of RAM and use it for school, as a replacement for my worn windows laptop, but I'm wondering if I'd be able to run Android Studio and possibly other software on it. I don't plan on doing any android dev with it, I just need it to compile LibGDX Gradle builds while I'm bored, coding at school. Would this be possible? If not, is there an alt to Android Studio on Linux that would allow me to compile and build my code? If that's not possible, would it be practical to RDP to my PC at home or something?

Comment: In my experience Android Studio is pretty memory hungry, not sure 4GB is going to work well.  I don't see why RDP shouldn't work though as long as you can get that set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

You might get full linux on Chromebook and install any available software for your disributive. This links contains all necessary information:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrome_OS_devices

http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/